# UILocalNotifications while app is in foreground

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I know similar types of question have been asked before but I'm trying to achieve a particular effect:

I understand I can listen in,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

and handle the notification myself, however I don't just want to display a custom alert or UIAlertView,

I actually want the UILocalNotification to show as it would when the app is in the background.
i.e.

[image: Banner Notification]

The reason i'd like this is, it's play a sound itself, and the banner looks pretty.

Any thoughts?

Regards,
John

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only two solutions come to mind. The first is not feasible: it would involve creating another app with a different signature and somehow have it manage the notifications. I don't even want to think this through - it seems like a bad idea.

Therefore, you just have to reengineer the notification popup. A simple view with rounded corners, animating in via rotation etc. Should be doable without too much trouble.

Comment: Ahh I see so you are suggesting, recreating the effect manually? I guess this means there is no [myNotification show] method then!?!

Answer (score 5):

This control might help you achieve the effect you're seeking:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mpnotificationview

Comment: Pretty nice thanks! - None of these support audio alerts, I'm not sure why, I guess I could just add the audioalert to the mpnotificationView code myself using system sounds right?

Comment: Yup, sounds doable. Good luck